# Removing object files in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I have created a yaml file to test a pipleline (CI/CD in Gitlab).
The first job builds the code that generates objects file.

The second job uses those objects files to perform further tests.

But in the pipeline, when it switches from the first job to the other, it deletes all the object files, and hence the following test using those object files fails. There is a whole list of object files that it removes. The log shows " Removing ...................." for all the object files.

I tried using the dependency variable (needs) but it does not work. Added the object file folder in ./gitignore but no success. It still removes the object files.

```
    stages:
  - build
  - test

build-code-job:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /home/abc/*
  script:
    - make -j99
    - wait

test-code-job:
  stage: test
  needs: [build-code-job]
  script:
    - wait
    - echo "Testing complete"
    - insmod abc.ko
```

Any idea how it could be resolved. I don't want to delete the object files.

Comment: can you add the relevant excerpts of the CI file and job outputs?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the object files as `artifacts:` ? If not, I believe the behavior you described is expected -- In general, all jobs start with the same clean workspace. If you need files to persist across jobs, that's a use case for `artifacts:`.